# How do I set locale of DatePickerIOS in react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

My program has localization and I want to pass a locale to the DatePickerIOS in react-native so it automatically changes to 12 hours/24 hour clock. However, I'm not really sure how to do it on the native side of IOS since I'm not quite familiar with it. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can expose the locale property of UIDatePicker so I can set it in react-native?

For example, . This would return a 24 hour hour clock.

Thanks